# Корректное указание времени прибытия

Tags: грамотная-речь

Оба выражения являются грамотными?

Я приехал вчера в 9.
Я приехал вчера к 9.

Answer (score 1):

Оба выражения являются грамотными — так можно говорить, а вот писать числа лучше прописью, в особенности те, которые используются в падежной форме и без уточнения (часов, утра, вечера...).

Я приехал туда вечером и отдал распоряжение, что завтра в 9 часов утра мною будет произведён смотр... (К. М. Оберучев);
Было уже около одиннадцати часов вечера, когда я приехал на ближайшую к Лиммериджу станцию; Завтрак будет подан в девять часов (У. Коллинз);
После 9 часов пополудни Лермонтов приехал в Тамань, но в связи с пребыванием в городе... (В. Захаров);
**К девяти часам** вечера министры стали собираться в заседание... (Н. Покровский);
Около десяти часов я приехал в деревню Богас-Шой, где я должен был явиться к командиру... Ну хорошо, я вас буду ждать **к двенадцати часам** (М. Скобелев).

**Я приехал вчера в девять** — говорящий уверен в том, что он приехал **ровно** в девять часов.

**Я приехал вчера к девяти** — время прибытия обозначено **приблизительно**: до девяти, около девяти, почти в девять, незадолго до девяти (то есть в тот момент, когда девять часов ещё не наступило).

Answer (score 0):

Оба варианта верны, но у них разное значение.

В 9 означает ровно в указанное время. К 9 означает до указанного времени.

Comment: "К девять" не говорят. Говорят "к девяти".

Comment: Ну это и так ясно. Я написал просто цифрами.